# Why can I not copy directories to a WEBDAV mount?

Tags: webdav, owncloud, davfs2

I am trying to copy files from my primary data storage server into an OwnCloud instance. The data storage server has successfully mounted the user's directory on the OwnCLoud server, via webdav. I can copy files from the data server to the OwnCloud server; I can mkdir on OwnCLoud from the data server. However, I cannot recursively copy a directory from the data server. I get, for each directory I am trying to copy:
`cannot create directory '/path/to/dir\ with\ spaces\ in\ name': Invalid argument`

Here is the command I am using:
`cp -R /dir/* /mnt/point/`

Both servers are Linux. However, there are windows file and directory names (with spaces) in the directory I am trying to copy. I think that the issue is with the directory name having spaces in it.

Comment: Can you use rsync?

Comment: @mdpc I wish I could! The OwnCloud system won't let me just copy the files into the folders for some reason. Regardless, I found the solution...I am about to post it as an answer. Thanks for reading and helping!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem does seem to have been in the naming of directories. Instead of using the slash delimiter for the space, I had to wrap the directory names in quotes. (I didn't know Linux saw any difference in the 2 methods)

In the commands where I was using directory names, this did not work:
`/path/to/dir\ with\ spaces\ in\ name`

This did:
`"/path/to/dir with spaces in name"`

If anyone knows why, I would love to know.

Comment: The OS stops interpreting once it hits a space. Adding " " makes it interpret the entire block, not just up to the space